# Make top div as wide as the div below it

Tags: html, css

See this: http://jsfiddle.net/90d7144p/

I want the width of the DIV with class `rect` be as long as its underlying DIVs with class `box`. Class `box` should not be changed (at least minimum changes). Also, the boxes are not aligned by tables. I don't care for the size of the container (black border).

This

[image]

should be

[image]

CSS:

```
* { margin: 2px; }

.container { width: 100%; border: 1px solid black; }

.box { display: inline-block; width:100px; height:100px; border: 1px solid red; }

.rect { border: 1px solid green; }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="rect">The width must be as long as underlying boxes.</div>
    <div class="box">BOX</div> <div class="box">BOX</div>
    <div class="box">BOX</div> <div class="box">BOX</div>
    <div class="box">BOX</div> <div class="box">BOX</div>
    <div class="box">BOX</div> <div class="box">BOX</div>
    <div class="box">BOX</div>
</div>
```

Is there any CSS or HTML based solution?

Comment: And you don't want to use JS to set width of `.rect` right? Any reason?

Comment: So you're saying that it's impossible to align them without JS?

Comment: Hmm, you could use media queries to specify width of `.rect` depending on how many `.box` fit on one row. No JavaScript required, but not ideal at the same time.

Comment: I am not saying that. However, at the moment I can't think of a css-only solution. Thinking.. Is the space between boxes fixed? or it is allowed to change?

Comment: It can be changed, however the main layout should be like the desired picture.

Comment: Why doing it this way around? If you want the largest element to adapt to several smaller ones you'll need JS to calculate the sum.
It makes more sens to me to adapt the small boxes to the rectangle. Either with percentages (margins in % if you want to keep a 100px width) or by using tables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a solution based on my comment above, it uses media queries:

Since the boxes are fixed width, it is possible to pre-determine how many boxes fit one one line if the screen is [x0, x1] pixels wide. You can feed this information to CSS media queries to create several rules, each one specifies the width of the box for a given range of widths. Here is an example (generated using excel):

```
                                        .rect { width: 100px; }
@media screen and (min-width:  214px) { .rect { width: 206px; } }
@media screen and (min-width:  320px) { .rect { width: 312px; } }
@media screen and (min-width:  426px) { .rect { width: 418px; } }
@media screen and (min-width:  532px) { .rect { width: 524px; } }
@media screen and (min-width:  638px) { .rect { width: 630px; } }
@media screen and (min-width:  744px) { .rect { width: 736px; } }
@media screen and (min-width:  850px) { .rect { width: 842px; } }
@media screen and (min-width:  956px) { .rect { width: 948px; } }
```

[**Code**](http://jsfiddle.net/90d7144p/11/), [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/90d7144p/11/show/)

Notes:

- I used multiples of 106px (100px + 2px border + 4px margin).
- `min-width` is the width of screen, not that of container. 2px were added to compensate for black border.
- The widths of the rectangle start from 100, not 106 since they already have 2px border and 4px margin.
- The order of @media rules matter (min-widths ascending).
- The width of "space" (such as the one between two inline block) depends on various factors including font family and size; I've floated the boxes so that they become block elements and spaces do not count.

Answer (score 8):

You could use media queries, to specify the width of rect each time a box collapses to the next line. This involves calculating each break point and aply a media query to it.

To make calculations easier, you should use floats so that the white-space between elements doesn't ruin your layout.

The following demo needs tweaking but it should show you what I am talking about :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/90d7144p/7/)** (resize the result window above 650px  wide to see it works)

*CSS example:*

```
@media screen and (min-width: 742px) and (max-width: 847px){
    .rect {
        width: 736px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution, lets optimize this further.

You can change your markup like this. (added a `.stretch` div)

```
    ...
    <div class="box">BOX</div>
    <div class="box">BOX</div>
    <div class="stretch"></div>
</div>
```

And CSS,

```
.stretch {
    height: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: justify;
    padding: 2px;
}

* {
    margin: 2px 0;
}
```

This way, `BOX`es will align to occupy the full width of the parent.

However, the last row won't have same space in between.

Comment: The problem in your solution is that when we maximize the window the rect will not be aligned. [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z62szon4/)

Comment: That's trivial, adding `display: inline-block;` solves that issue, but the last row problem bothers me.

Comment: Is width of `.box` fixed?

Answer (score -3):

IF and Only IF you want to do it simply by using JQuery then following is the code for your query.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
* { margin: 2px; }

.container { width: 100%; border: 1px solid black; }

.box { display: inline-block; width:100px; height:100px; border: 1px solid red; }

.rect { border: 1px solid green; }
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
  resize();
  $(window).resize(function(){
    resize();   
  });
  function resize()
  {
    var max = 0, $element;
        $('.box').each(function()
        {
            if($(this).offset().left > max)
            {
                max = $(this).offset().left;
                $element = $(this);
            }
        });

        $(".rect").css("width",max+90);
  }
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="rect">The width must be as long as underlying boxes.</div>
    <div class="box">BOX</div> <div class="box">BOX</div>
    <div class="box">BOX</div> <div class="box">BOX</div>
    <div class="box">BOX</div> <div class="box">BOX</div>
    <div class="box">BOX</div> <div class="box">BOX</div>
    <div class="box">BOX</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```